Need help with adaptive meshing code
I am trying to understand adaptive meshing and is using this code (https://github.com/esquivas/amr1d) as a reference. However, there is no documentation for it and thus, it is hard for me to understand. For instance, in the init_mesh subroutine, the active blocks are initialized with
ActiveBlocks(:) = -1,
ActiveBlocks(1) =  4,
ActiveBlocks(2) = 10,
ActiveBlocks(3) = 22,
ActiveBlocks(4) = 23,
ActiveBlocks(5) = 24,
ActiveBlocks(6) = 31,
ActiveBlocks(7) = 7,
ActiveBlocks(8) = 13,
How does the author know which numbers to assign to each of the active blocks? When I try changing the values, the code does not run finish as it exceeds the allowable refinement limit or give me wrong results.

That really does seem to be a question only the author of the code can answer -- why don't you ask them? Separately, though: There are large, exceedingly well documented, widely used, well tested, and professionally developed open source libraries for adaptive mesh refinement. Why use a random project that is not documented and hasn't been maintained in 7 years?

Noted, I am new to AMR and am trying to learn it from 1D case first as starting point. Most of the open source libraries seem to have AMR and MPI implemented together which makes learning AMR harder and I do not have access to the large machines.

Most of the libraries in question can run on single machines, and single processors, too. deal.II for example (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors) runs just fine on a single machine and the large majority of tutorial programs do exactly this.

Thank you I know how to write already.

As mentioned in the comments, that is something you would need to consult the author of the code for.
Not sure if you're a PhD or a Masters, but if so, there wouldn't be too many different methods that you need to use. And if you're going to specialize in this field, I actually suggest you write your own code after studying the adaptive meshing. Begin with learning FEM and write your code for it. There are many books out there you can learn, to then be able to write a code for it. In the end, you just need to know how to mesh and then compute the mass matrix, stiffness matrix, load vector etc.
Once you've written your own code for FEM you will be much more hands on with it. Then, do the adaptive meshing.
Many people don't bother writing their own codes but honestly, there is going to be a difference in the level of understanding amongst those who wrote their own code and those who didn't. Especially, because FEM is used very widely.

Happy to have this answer deleted because it doesn't answer your question. I don't have enough points to be able to directly comment for your post. But hope that you get a chance to read it before it gets removed.

Why would you spend a year or more of your life writing a piece of software that others have already done so much better? I get that writing a small piece of software as an exercise makes sense, but not a whole research code. You will only ever be able to do what others have already done 20 years ago.
